# How to execute the simple python script from robot frame work

Tags: robotframework

I am new to the python and Robot frame work. I have a python script at below location "C:\Python33\sample.py"

```
print ('Hello world')
```

I have installed the RF and I have a robot file (test.robot) at same location with below content.

```
# example.robot
*** Settings ***
| Library | Process
*** Test Cases ***
| | ${result}= | run process | python | /C:/Python33/sample.py
```

When I tried to execute the file from command prompt getting errors

```
C:\Python33>robot test.robot

Error: "Testcase name cannot be empty"
```

Please help me to fix this

Answer (score 3):

By modifying below code in robot file testcase is passing

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | Process

*** Test Cases ***
Using Kwargs
| | ${result}= | run process | python | "C:/Python33/sample.py"
```

Comment: For completeness, I would like to add that you can also use the robotframework keyword 'Evaluate' for evaluating simple python expressions. [link](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate)