# How to use Robot Framework to call a .exe file(C# Console Application)?

Tags: exe, robotframework

I am using the Robot Framework to do a Automated test.What I will do is running an exe file by Robot Framework,and then check out the database whether the business data is correct.And I am good at testing the API,as for testing an .exe file,I am a newcomer,even I don't know how to do it,have you ever done it before?Thx a lot!

I used the "Run Process" keyword,but I did not get what I want.

```
 *** Settings ***
Library           Process

*** Test Cases ***
test
${Res}    Run Process    D:\\CompanyDocuments\\TestCases\\TestProject\\ConsoleApplication1\\EncryptDB\\bin\\Debug\\EncryptDB.exe    timeout=10s
Log    ${Res}
```

However,it says "Process did not complete in 10 seconds."I make sure the exe file could run correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "Run Process" keyword from Process Library
 or 
"Run", "Run and Return RC" from Operating System Library

Refer this link
[How to execute the simple python script from robot frame work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524741/how-to-execute-the-simple-python-script-from-robot-frame-work)

Comment: :Look at my supplementary info.Could you show me a right and clear example?

Answer (score 0):

```
${Res}    Run    D:\\CompanyDocuments\\TestCases\\TestProject\\ConsoleApplication1\\ConsoleApplication1\\bin\\Debug\\ConsoleApplication1.exe
Log    ${Res}
```

This code can get the right answer.Thanks Rakesh.I used the **Run** keyword in the **OperatingSystem** Libirary.